# Changing Custom theme color in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, css

MY custom theme extends Magento Blank theme.Following this link,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-practice.html 
I added _theme.less in my css/source folder & placed the code provided on above link in it.Flushed the cache.
But still changes are not reflecting on my site.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The [topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-practice.html) you referenced states:

> After the Grey theme is applied, store pages will look like following:

You need to **apply** your theme after you create the theme's files.

---

### Apply a theme

After you [add your theme to the file system](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html), you can apply it to your store. You apply a theme in Admin.

To apply a theme:

1. In Admin, go to **Stores** > **Configuration** > **Design**.
2. In the **Store View** drop-down field, select the store view where you want to apply the theme.
3. On the **Design Theme** tab, select your newly created theme in the **Design Theme** drop-down.
4. Click **Save Config**.
5. If caching is enabled, [clear the cache](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html#theme-apply-clear).
6. To see your changes applied, reload the store front pages.

See [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html#theme-apply-apply) for more information.